# SQL over Big data for datascience

Tags: large-data, sql

I just started to learn data science, i am not able to decide if i should go with SQL or Big Data, which one would be more helpful for a data scientist. if anyone would help me to understand this then it would be really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL is a query language used by many different databases. “Big data“ is a broad, catch-all, term for many different, pretty diverse, technologies. It’s like asking if it is better to learn Spanish, or “Asian languages”. Moreover, many of the query languages that can be used with big data databases are based on SQL, do you need to learn it first. I don’t think that there are tech, or data related, jobs where knowing SQL won’t be helpful.

Comment: so, are you saying that i can use sql queries in bigdata?

Comment: Big data is not a collection of query languages (and strictly speaking, not a collection of technologies, though the intended meaning is probably captured this way), so SQL and big data are not directly comparable. A more accurate parallel would perhaps be Spanish vs. grammar than Spanish vs. Asian languages.

Comment: @LijinDurairaj there’s no such a thing like “big data”, there are many different technologies. Forget about “big data”, focus rather on learning particular skills, or technologies that you actually need, or are needed to find a job you are looking for, the job descriptions are often pretty specific on what they need (“big query”, “kafka”, “spark” etc).